# HTACCESS Rewrite Rule Conflict for User and User Post

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am having a problem finding the correct reg-exp for two rewrite rules. I am checking that the filename is not a valid directory, file or link and then proceeding with the two rewrite rules if this is the case. Separately they work but if i have them both turned on, there is a conflict.

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ([^/][a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ /post.php?no=$2
RewriteRule ([^/][a-zA-Z]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1
```

The desired urls are;
 
User Post:  ...com/username/81
User profile:  ...com/username

Any suggestions would be much appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule` but you have 2nd `RewriteCond` without any `RewriteCond`. Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ([^/][a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ /post.php?no=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ([^/][a-zA-Z]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, thaat seems to have done the trick. Can you just clarify what the RewriteRule ^ - [L] is doing. Thnaks again.

Comment: Glad it worked. `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` part basically means **do nothing** if request is for a valid file/directory/link.